# How to prevent large Magma Cubes from spawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to prevent Magma Cubes from spawning in my Zombie Pigman gold farm. The largest Magma Cubes are slowly killing my Iron Golems = big problem.

I'm considering lowering the roof, making the cage just 2 blocks tall. Will this be suficient to prevent the largest Magma Cubes from spawning? Since this will also prevent Ghasts from spawning (right?), I'm wondering if there are any better ways to do this?

**EDIT:** I just realized that if I lower the roof to 2 height, there's no room for Iron Golems in the cage :\

Comment: For the farm, is it just a cage with Iron Golems in the nether? The Zombie Pigmen will spawn then the Golems to kill them right?

Comment: @sensiwoo Yes, it's an Etho/Docm design. Like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwZsBcrH9Rg&t=17m43s

Comment: If you lower the roof to 2, you can still use that to lower the ceiling around the iron golems to trap them in place.  Have you thought about doing that with a bunch of iron golems?  It should keep the farm going, but the iron golems being in 1 place should keep the large magma cubes from spawning.

Comment: That could work, I guess - but sounds very expensive. I'd need like 40-50 iron golems to cover the cage. Sounds like the golems would occupy lots of space too, decreasing spawn rates for pigmen significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Make the cage smaller in width. No other way, I think.

Comment: Is the group spawn mechanism different for Zombie Pigmen and Magma Cubes? Both mob types spawn in groups, right?

Comment: Yes. For the appearance of magma cubes take up more space than Pigmen.

Comment: It also prevent Ghasts from spawning.